# Что за проблема при установке Django?

Tags: django

Что за проблема при установке Django ?
Обновил pip[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какую команду вводите?

Comment: pip install Django==2.1.7

Comment: Уже установлена джанга. Попробуйте ```django-admin.py ``` в терминале

Comment: нету таких папок в тотале

Comment: django-admin запускается?

Comment: На скриншоте вместо команды вводится сообщение, которое ранее выдал pip.